# Django. Браузер не видит media-файлы по абсолютному пути

Tags: css, django, изображения, path

Простая задача - показать на странице `div` с фоном-картинкой. Для этого в описании стиля css используется абсолютный путь url:

**CSS**

```
.ico-add {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(/media/pics/add.ico);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ico-add"></div>
```

При этом в диспетчере **urls.py** корень приложения задан следующим образом:

**URLS**

```
url(r'^$', app.views.home, name='home'),
```

а сами media-файлы находятся в соответствующей папке: **my-app/media/pics**,

тем не менее, браузер упорно не желает видеть файл **add.ico** с сообщением в консоли:

```
GET http://localhost:50000/media/pics/add.ico 404 (Not Found)
```

Подкажите, возможен ли такой подход в принципе или необходимо связывать требуемые файлы со статическим контентом и прописывать к ним доступ через тег `{%static '<local_path>' %}` ??

Comment: Django не занимается раздачей статических файлов, это задача настроенного веб-сервера